# Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, mysql

I insert data array into database like this :

```
$value['gallery_data'] = array();
$value['gallery_data'] = serialize((array(array_values("name"), array_values("url"), array_values("type")))); // LINE 843
```

In database:

```
a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;N;i:2;N;}
```

I see this error in action:

```
Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\editnews.php on line 843

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\editnews.php on line 843

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\user\modules\editnews.php on line 843
```

**EDIT:**

I need to insert this format for multiple array in database:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{i:0;s:48:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg";i:1;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/IMG_4181.jpg";i:2;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/swan_002.jpg";i:3;s:45:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/zzmed copy.jpg";}i:1;a:4:{i:0;s:19:"test_title";i:1;s:20:"test_title1";i:2;s:25:"test_title2";i:3;s:24:"677777777777777777777777";}i:2;a:4:{i:0;s:19:"test_alt";i:1;s:21:"test_alt1";i:2;s:21:"test_alt2";i:3;s:26:"77888888888888888888888888";}}
```

how do can i fix this ?

Comment: Warning clearly says `array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array`

Comment: you need to do unserialize before passing this array in array_values() function.

Comment: Please [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for the `array_values()` function - you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: hey it is a json encode string .

Answer (score 1):

I feel you are using `array_values` before array so try something like this

```
$value['gallery_data'] = serialize(array_values(array("key1" => "name", "key2" => "url", "key3" => "type")));
```

or like this

```
$value['gallery_data'] = serialize(array("name" , "url", "type")); // LINE 843
```

Comment: I didn't get your point? If you want to insert it in db than you can insert it in db and un-serialize it after your retrieve it. if you are looking for something different than describe it clearly

Comment: No need of `array_value()` here

Answer (score 1):

No need of `array_value()` here

**Reason**

---

```
print_r(array("name", "url", "type"));
//output
Array ( [0] => name [1] => url [2] => type )
//output
print_r(array_values(array("name", "url", "type")));
Array ( [0] => name [1] => url [2] => type )
```

Try:

```
$value['gallery_data'] = serialize(array("name", "url", "type")); // LINE 843
```

### Updates

## [WORKING DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v3kx-67kr)

Passing multiple array in single array like this:

Try:

```
$value['gallery_data'] = array();
echo $value['gallery_data'] = serialize(array(
    array(
        "uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg", 
        "uploads/media/galleries/nature/IMG_4181.jpg", 
        "uploads/media/galleries/nature/swan_002.jpg",
        "uploads/media/galleries/nature/zzmed copy.jpg",
    ),
    array("test_title", 
          "test_title1", 
          "test_title2",
          "test_title3"
         ),
    array("test_alt",
          "test_alt1",
          "test_alt2",
          "test_alt3"
    )
)); // LINE 843
```

Output as you want:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{i:0;s:48:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/butterfly_001.jpg";i:1;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/IMG_4181.jpg";i:2;s:43:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/swan_002.jpg";i:3;s:45:"uploads/media/galleries/nature/zzmed copy.jpg";}i:1;a:4:{i:0;s:10:"test_title";i:1;s:11:"test_title1";i:2;s:11:"test_title2";i:3;s:11:"test_title3";}i:2;a:4:{i:0;s:8:"test_alt";i:1;s:9:"test_alt1";i:2;s:9:"test_alt2";i:3;s:9:"test_alt3";}}
```

Comment: Want to see your coee @user27133

Comment: Your Code Work for multiple data array?! i.e: 5 image_url , 5 title, 5 alt.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string to the `array_values` function instead of an array.

So replace `array_values("name")` with `array_values($someArray)` for example.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php